# Why the first element of response is null in serverless?

Tags: request, aws-lambda, httpresponse, serverless

I am new in serverless framework, I try to creat some lambda function.
I find the interesting stuff, the handler of request always be null, for instance.

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    ....
    callback(null, 'Success!');
```

}

what is the first element of the callback response meanning?
If the element is not null, what it should be?
why it should be null?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same doubt, here are my observations.

1. If the first parameter is not null, it indicates error, that lambda is failed.
2. It will add the metric to CloudWatch and you can trigger alarm based on the failures.
3. If you have a synchronous calls from a trigger such as DynamoDB streams, Amazon Kinesis, those adapters will retry the call it back until it the call to lambda succeeds.
4. Also the first parameter in most languages are not optional, if forces you to evaluate whether the function is successful or not. Since there are other dependencies the infrastructure (some mentioned above) need to make based on that value.

Hope it helps.